# How to convert stream into variables in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, graph-algorithm

There is a input file(file.in).

```
4  
5   
1 2  
2 4  
3 1  
3 4  
4 2
```

In typescript, reading input file line by line.

```
const graphsMain = () => {

    let lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
        input: require('fs').createReadStream('file.in')
    });

    lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
        console.log('Line from file:', line);
    });
}

graphsMain();
```

In C++, I can do that with the coding.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool A[10][10];

int main() {
  int x, y, nodes, edges;
  cin >> nodes; // Number of nodes
  cin >> edges; // Number of edges
  for (int i = 0; i < edges; ++i) {
    cin >> x >> y;
    A[x][y] = true; 
  }

  return 0;
}
```

However, I don't know how to implement in typescript. Please feel free to comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that if you're coming from C++ into the Javascript world there is a big conceptual difference in how the code you write is actually executed. C++ heavily relies on synchronous execution while the Javascript world is more focused on asynchronous execution.

The concrete problem you're trying to solve would be achieved in this way using the asynchronous Node APIs you attempt to use:

```
// imports, or require()s as in your code are like conceptually equivalent
// to #include in C++, hence should be at the beginning of the file, not somewhere
// in the middle.
import * as fs from 'fs'
import * as readline from 'readline'

const graphsMain = () => {
    let lineReader = readline.createInterface({
        input: fs.createReadStream('file.in')
    });

    let lineCount = 0;
    let nodes: number | undefined
    let edges: number | undefined
    let buffer: number[][] = []
    lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
        console.log('Line from file:', line);
        if (lineCount == 0) {
          nodes = parseInt(line) 
        } else if (lineCount == 1) {
          edges = parseInt(line)
        } else {
          const coordinates = line.split(' ').map((item) => parseInt(item)) 
          buffer.push(coordinates)
        }
        lineCount++
    });

    lineReader.on('close', function () {
        console.log('end. I got these values:', nodes, edges, buffer)   
    });
}

graphsMain();
```

That said, you can solve it in a multitude of different ways, including a synchronous API like `fs.readFileSync` that you might be more familiar with.

As I feel your Javascript Journey is just starting out though, I would highly recommend you doing some reading up on the emphasis the whole ecosystem relies on asynchronous code execution. [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous) has a great series of articles explaining all that.